# How to insert a float into a JSON object in non scientific notation

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a JSON object and I would like to add a property to it with a float/decimal value. The few approaches I've tried to do this seem to produce less than ideal outcomes. I'll jump straight into code examples because they're simple and illustrate the issue better than words

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{}'
DECLARE @floatInStringForm VARCHAR(20) = '6780.75'

SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.TestFloat', CAST(@floatInStringForm AS FLOAT))
SELECT @json
```

**Desired JSON**

```
{"TestFloat":6780.75}
```

**Actual JSON**

```
{"TestFloat":6.780750000000000e+003}
```

After a bit of googling, I tried something very similar, but using the DECIMAL type instead:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{}'
DECLARE @floatInStringForm VARCHAR(20) = '6780.75'

SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.TestFloat', CAST('6780.75' AS DECIMAL(20, 10)))
SELECT @json
```

This results in something closer to the desired JSON:

```
{"TestFloat":6780.7500000000}
```

with the main downside that we end up with a bunch of extra trailing zeros until we hit our scale limit. We could drop the scale to 2 and that would remove trailing zeros, but we need to be able to handle any (reasonable) number that could be provided to us and not everything is guaranteed to only have two decimal places. Is there any solution that can produce the desired JSON shown above but still have the flexibility to handle more than 2 decimal places?

I'd expect behavior to be pretty consistent across SQL Server versions, but here's the @@VERSION we're using in case you need to know

**Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec  6 2023 08:32:07   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation**

Comment: `float/decimal value` - float and decimal are completely different number types, you need to choose which one you want. From your examples I think you want decimal...

Comment: And your issue with decimal, trailing zeros, who cares? The number is still precisely the same. And you must have some idea how many decimal places the value could reasonably be (your scale limit?), which you could shorten to if required.

Comment: I agree, it does sound like decimal is what I want. I was just illustrating my thought process as we started out with float. And you're right that the trailing zeros don't really matter other than resulting in a slightly longer JSON string that we're storing in the DB. We can certainly live with that, I just wanted to pose the question in case there was a simple solution I wasn't aware of.

We could probably reasonably impose a 4 decimal place limit or something like that, but the concern there is that these numbers are coming from user input and users can be unpredictable

Comment: Users can be unpredictable, but whatever you are requesting of them should have limited, enforced by validation. Your business context will have limits to what is acceptable.

Comment: `resulting in a slightly longer JSON string that we're storing in the DB` - why are you storing the JSON in the database? Use the correct datatype and this issue doesn't come about.

Comment: `I just wanted to pose the question in case there was a simple solution I wasn't aware of.` But there isn't actual a problem to have a solution to.

Comment: `why are you storing the JSON in the database? Use the correct datatype and this issue doesn't come about` I appreciate the advice, but as developers we are sometimes trapped by the constraints of the system we're working in. I can't just go in and rewrite our company's entire application because prior developers did something in a less than ideal manner

Comment: Fair enough, but thats all useful context to add to your question upfront. On this site people will always call out best practice, so being clear about what you are doing (storing the JSON in the database - which you don't mention in the question and makes a difference) and that you are unable to change that, will avoid getting such comments :) because most people will assume you are generating JSON to transfer to another system, and in that scenario the number of trailing zeros makes absolutely no difference. (In your case too to be fair, the database can handle a few additional characters)

Comment: *I hate it when a format that is designed to be both human and computer readable is implemented in such a way as to say "screw the human".* Technically, the value `6.780750000000000e+003` is perfectly valid and exactly equal to `6780.75` (both are JSON `number` types) , but the exponential form sure isn't human friendly. It doesn't even save space.

Comment: JSON is all text, and you already have the desired format in your string; why do you have the CAST(... as FLOAT)? If your problem is that you already have floats (not varchars), then you can inject them into JSON string by using format(@FloatVar,'R')

Comment: @tinazmu - If you don't CAST the string to a float/decimal/numeric before you pass it into JSON_MODIFY, it goes into the JSON object as a string instead of a number. Or at least that's how it seemed to behave to me

Comment: Json is all text, so the the only difference is having double quotes around strings. What harm is there if you store them in Jason with quotes?